# Go периодический опрос серверов. Перестает принимать данные

Tags: golang

Имеется скрипт, который каждую секунду опрашивает сервера. Каждый сервер опрашивается в своем потоке. Первоначально работает так как и задумано, но после пары дней работы начинаются проблемы - один из потоков перестает получать данные с сервера. При этом статус работающего процесса становиться "спящим". После перезапуска программы все начинает стабильно работать.

```
func main()  {
    serv, err := getServ(conn) //  получение списка серверов
    if(err != nil){
        panic(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    countThread = 0
    for _, element := range serv{
        fmt.Println(element)
        go poll(&countThread, element)
    }
}

func poll(countThread *int, serv Server){
    *countThread++
    ip := serv.Ip
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ip + ":2020")
    if(err != nil){
        *countThread--
        fmt.Println("Error connect")
        time.Sleep(10)
        go poll(countThread, serv)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    for{
        conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 20))
        conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 20))
        a, b, z, option, e := writeCommand(conn) // получаем данные

    }
}

func writeCommand(){
     servComm := []byte{0x68, 0x04, 0x00, 0x04, 0x08}
     conn.Write(servComm)
     resInc := make([]byte, 14)
     conn.Read(resInc)
     return resInc
}
```

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что у вас тут гонки?

Comment: Новичек в Golang. Потому, если можете чуть подробнее рассказать? Хотелось бы разобраться.

Comment: Скорей всего у вас исчерпан лимит на открытые сокеты.

Comment: @prospero78su, получает скрипт опрашивает устройство и не закрывая старый сокет открывает новый?

Comment: @KordDEM скорей всего так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ох.  В вашем коде столько плохого, что никто вам не скажет, какая из
написанных вами мин взрывается первой.  Начнём с очевидного:

```golang
*countThread++
```

У вас из нескольких потоков выполнения идёт ничем не защищённый
неатомарный инкремент.  Это же пример
[гонки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8)
прямиком из учебников!  Это исправляется с помощью средств из пакетов
`sync` и `sync/atomic`.

```golang
if(err != nil){
    panic(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Зачем вы делаете `os.Exit` после паники?  Этот код никогда не
будет выполнен.

```golang
time.Sleep(10)
```

Вы точно уверены, что хотите спать **десять наносекунд**?

```golang
// …
conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 20))
conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 20))
// …
conn.Write(servComm)
// …
conn.Read(resInc)
// …
```

Ни одной проверки ошибки!  Ну и да, у вас дедлайны на чтение и запись
получаются разные.

Помимо прочего, ваш код не отформатирован с помощью `go fmt`
и что-то мне подсказывает, что `go vet`,
`errcheck`, `staticcheck`, и иными средствами
статического анализа кода вы не пользовались.  Пожалуйста, исправьте
свой код и научитесь пользоваться инструментами!